# Why is the component property undefined when called in another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, properties

I am working on an Angular project where I am authenticating my user and I want to get the current authenticated user which works fine. I set the component user property in `NgOnInit()` but then I try to access the property in another function and it undefined there even though I have assigned it a value of the authenticated user. Why is that and how do I prevent it from happening?

Here is my code:

```
NgOnInit()  {
   this.setCurrentUser();
   this.getData();
}



  setCurrentUser() {
     Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user=> {
      console.log(user);
      this.currentUser = user;
    })
  }

   getData = () => {
    console.log("DATA USER:")
    console.log(this.user)
  }
```

Comment: Try calling `getData` in `.then` block if it works there, it's undefined because you are mixing async and sync logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of aync function Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(). you can use async...await or call the getData() in then()
then approach

```
    setCurrentUser() {
     Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user=> {
      console.log(user);
      this.currentUser = user;
      this.getData();
    })
  }
```

Async...await approach

```
async NgOnInit()  {
   await this.setCurrentUser();
   this.getData();
}

  setCurrentUser() {
     return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user=> {
      console.log(user);
      this.currentUser = user;
    })
  }

   getData = () => {
    console.log("DATA USER:")
    console.log(this.user)
  }
```

Comment: Isn't it a bad practise to make NgOnInit() async?

Comment: It depends on situation. Situation where everything should be populated before exiting ngOnInit() we can make use of async.

Comment: I followed your example but it still undefined.

Comment: setCurrentUser() should return a promise